# SQL Server 2017 configuration manager missing reporting services service

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2017-express

This question has been been asked before, but no one has answered it. I installed SQL Server 2017 Express, created a database and installed the Reporting Services (which now is a separate download).

Everything is working, BUT, when I open the SQL Server Configuration Manager, EVERYTHING is there but the SQL Server Reporting Services service.

I have to go to `services.msc` to start and stop it under the title 'SQL Server Reporting Services'. Did something go wrong with my install? Does the 2017 version of Reporting Services no no longer go in the SQL Server Configuration Manager? Is there something that can be done to get it there or do I have to uninstall and try again?

Thank you in advance!

James

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nothing went wrong.  Because SQL Server Reporting Services is a separate product, it's no longer included in the tools used to manage SQL.  While I do not have any documentation for this, I experienced the same thing in SQL 2019.